# useStyles hook not working in Material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am trying to add css styling to a material-ui component but the styling is not working ,check the button component i have addded **className ={classes.btn}**, there are no warning and errors given.

**here is the code**

```
import "./App.css";

import { Button, Container, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import KeyboardArrowRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight";

import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({

btn:{

  fontSize:50,
  backgroundColor:"green"
}  


})


function App() {
 
const classes = useStyles()
 
  return (
    <Container>
    
      <Button
    className={classes.btn}
        variant="contained"
        color="error"
        type="submit"
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("you clicked me ");
        }}
        endIcon={<KeyboardArrowRightIcon />}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  btn: {
    fontSize: "50px !important",
    backgroundColor: "green !important"
  }
});
```

[image: Edit tender-morning-t99zb]

Comment: thanks for helping , but it didn't worked

Comment: also u wrote class name to be root mine was btn , does that make any differnce as long as u pass it correctly in porps like classes.btn is also correct way

Comment: check official documentation it works perfectly but as i chage any property it does not work     https://mui.com/styles/basics/

Comment: @nodeDev Check the answer again.

Comment: I have the same issue, This , worked like charm in version 4, now you have to add pix and important ?? What is the deal here  ???

Comment: @Richardson Please upvote if it was helpful. It doesn't work without them!